# How to override default swgger-code-gen Service implementation?

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am new to swagger codegen and I use version 2.1.6. I am trying to generate rest service via yaml and swagger-codegen-maven.
Below is part of pom.xml:

```
.....
<plugin>
<groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${io.swagger.swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
      <id>createprod</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/rest-api-create-product.yaml</inputSpec>
            <language>io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaResteasyServerCodegen</language>
          <!--   <templateDirectory>How_do_I_use_it</templateDirectory> -->

            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
            <apiPackage>${swagger.resourcePackage}.handler</apiPackage>
            <modelPackage>${swagger.resourcePackage}.model</modelPackage>
            <invokerPackage>${swagger.resourcePackage}.handler</invokerPackage>
             <configOptions>
                 <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                 <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                 <configPackage>com.domain.service.configuration</configPackage>
                 <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
             </configOptions>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
  </plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/java</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

ServiceImpl generated by swagger is:

```
import com.domain.servie.handler.*;
import com.domain.servie.model.*;


import com.domain.servie.model.InitSuccessResponse;
import com.domain.servie.model.FailureResponse;
import com.domain.servie.model.InitRequest;

import java.util.List;
import com.domain.servie.handler.NotFoundException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;

@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaResteasyServerCodegen", date = "2017-01-13T12:19:29.084-06:00")
public class InitWfApiServiceImpl extends InitWfApiService {

      @Override
      public Response createProductPost(String apiKey,InitRequest body,SecurityContext securityContext)
      throws NotFoundException {
      // do some magic!
      return Response.ok().entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.OK, "magic!")).build();
  }

}
```

Here, instead of `return Response.ok().entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.OK, "magic!")).build();`, I would like to map request processing to my own request handler and I don't want to hardcode it to rest api.

The idea is, rest-api is to be reusable (jar file). The system that includes rest-api as dependency jar will take care of building war. Packaging structure is a sort of stone carved requirement given to me. :)

Does anyone know how do I override this ServiceImpl code WITHOUT doing some crazy stuff like overriding DefaultCodeGen etc ? Is it possible to use templates to achieve this?

Any input will be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template that generates that part of the code is [this one](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaJaxRS/resteasy/apiServiceImpl.mustache). 
You should be able to achieve the behaviour you need by changing the template.

Comment: After setting mustache template, I am able to create my service impl with template. But I faced odd scenario. since I have more than one API in yaml, I was not able to setup multiple service impl for different API. So workaround I took was create multiple yaml and run swagger-codegen. Any idea how to accommodate multiple service impls without creating multiple yaml ?

Comment: @bkrish I'm glad it worked but I don't know how to fix your new scenario, but ask a new question since someone else might know.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for the help!

Comment: no explanation of how to use the templateDirectory to override templates?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use custom templates you can use the following:

In maven add another plugin to download the maven dependency which contains the custom templates, you can upload them to your local artifactory for instance.
In this case the artifact is called swagger-templates and its version 0.0.1.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <resourceBundles>
      <resourceBundle>our.mvn.group:swagger-templates:0.0.1</resourceBundle>
    </resourceBundles>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then in the swagger-codegen-maven-plugin configuration section make sure to reference the correct directory, add this:

```
<templateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/maven-shared-archive-resources/subdir</templateDirectory>
```

Where subdir is a sub directory in the src/main/resources directory of the maven artifact which contains the custom templates. You can put your mustache files there.